# How to apply rolling mean function by axis 1 python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Simply we can calculate  mean by axis:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1],
                 'b':[1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1],
                 'c':[1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]}) 

# max_of_three columns 
mean= np.max(df.mean(axis=1))
```

How to do this same this with rolling mean ?

I tried 1:

```
# max_of_three columns 
mean=df.rolling(2).mean(axis=1)
```

got this error:

> UnsupportedFunctionCall: numpy operations are not valid with window objects. Use .rolling(...).mean() instead

I tried 2:

```
def tt(x):
    x=pd.DataFrame(x)
    b1=np.max(x.mean(axis=1))
    return b1

# max_of_three columns 
mean=df.rolling(2).apply(tt,raw=True)
```

But from here I get three columns in result, in real should be 1 value for each moving window.

Where I am doing mistake? or any other efficient way to doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `axis` argument in rolling as:

```
df.rolling(2, axis=0).mean()
>>>       A    b    c
    0   NaN  NaN  NaN
    1   1.0  1.0  1.0
    2   0.5  0.5  0.5
    3   0.5  0.5  0.5
    4   0.5  0.5  0.5
    5   0.5  0.5  0.5
    6   1.0  1.0  1.0
    7   0.5  0.5  0.5
    8   0.5  0.5  0.5
    9   1.0  1.0  1.0
    10  1.0  1.0  1.0

r = df.rolling(2, axis=1).mean()
r
>>>      A    b    c
    0  NaN  1.0  1.0
    2  NaN  0.0  0.0
    3  NaN  1.0  1.0
    4  NaN  0.0  0.0
    5  NaN  1.0  1.0
    6  NaN  1.0  1.0
    7  NaN  0.0  0.0
    8  NaN  1.0  1.0
    9  NaN  1.0  1.0
    10 NaN  1.0  1.0

r.max()
>>> A    NaN
    b    1.0
    c    1.0
    dtype: float64
```